# Make function and apply to read data in R?

Tags: r, import, dataset, fread

I have set of data (around 50000 data. and each one of them 1.5 mb). So, to load the data and process the data first I have used this code;

```
data <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.txt") # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory
```

then I use for loop to load each data;

```
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
data[[k]]<- read.csv(listcsv[k],sep = "",as.is = TRUE, comment.char = "",    skip=37);                                                                                                                                                       
my<- as.matrix(as.double(data[[k]][1:57600,2]));


print(ort_my);

a[k]<-ort_my;

write(a,file="D:/ddd/ads.txt",sep='\t',ncolumns=1)}
```

So, I set the program run but even if after 6 hours it didn't finished. Although I have a decent pc with a 32 GB ram and 6 core CPU.

I have searched the forum and maybe `fread` function would be helpful people say. However all the examples which I found so far deal with the single file reading with the `fread` function.

Can any one suggest me the solution of this problem for faster loop to read data and process it with these many rows and columns?

Comment: You're trying to read 75GB of data into memory? You may need to rethink your approach. If you can process one file at a time then you'll get better performance with the data.table `fread` function and you may be able to get this to run. Try first with a small number of files to estimate timing.

Comment: how long does it take to do say 100 files? It looks like each iteration in the loop is independent of previous iterations, if so you should look into splitting the workload between your 6 CPUs using the parallel package. You could turn it into a function and use `parLapply`

Comment: Thanks for prompt answers,
I have already calculated the time,
for 70 data it took 27.34 sec. (without fread)

So in total (50000 file) if I run this code at least 6 hours to finish:(

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing there has to be a way to make the extraction of what you want more efficient.  But I think running in parallel could save you a bunch of time.  And save you memory by not storing each file.

```
library("data.table")

#Create function you want to eventually loop through in parallel
readFiles <- function(x) {
   data <- fread(x,skip=37)
   my <- as.matrix(data[1:57600,2,with=F]);
   mesh <- array(my, dim = c(120,60,8));
   Ms<-1350*10^3    # A/m
   asd2=(mesh[70:75,24:36 ,2])/Ms;     # in A/m

   ort_my<- mean(asd2);
   return(ort_my)
}


#R Code to run functions in parallel

library(“foreach”);library(“parallel”);library(“doMC”)
detectCores() #This will tell you how many cores are available
registerDoMC(8) #Register the parallel backend

#Can change .combine from rbind to list
OutputList <- foreach(listcsv,.combine=rbind,.packages=c(”data.table”)) %dopar% (readFiles(x))

registerDoSEQ() #Very important to close out parallel backend.
```

Comment: dear @Mike.Ghan

now I have a trouble with the output of OutPutList, When I do

OutputList <- foreach(i=1:length(filelist),.combine='c', .packages=c("data.table")) %dopar% (readFiles) 

and try to write OutputList I can only write the function(x) not the "ort_my" please help!
aa<-OutputList
            
stopCluster(cl)

print(Sys.time()-strt)

write.table(aa, file="D:/Dropbox/ads.txt",sep='\t')

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583928/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-foreach-loop-in-r

@Mike.Gahan